# VB.NET how to allow people implement a class without letting people see or changing the code?

Tags: vb.net

How do you allow people to implement a class without letting them see or change the code?

Comment: You can always 1) compile your class into a binary assembly, 2) write the assembly to a .dll, and encrypt it, then 3) decrypt the .dll and dynamically load it at runtime.  But that seems a bit extreme, doesn't it?  Q: What's wrong with simplying using "private"???

Comment: Please be more specific. What do you mean by "implement a class"?  Do you mean write a class which implements an interface, or something else?  And what code do you want to prevent people from seeing?  It's pretty hard to figure out what scenario you want to support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Implementation* implies Interface. You can just define an Interface in a .NET assembly (.dll) which you provide to said people. There is no implementation in an interface. No code to change other than the property and method names and types.

```
Public Interface IFoo
    Sub Bar()
End Interface
```

If this code is given to people in a code file, they can change the definition of the Interface.

There is also an abstract class, in VB it is called MustInherit. Other classes can *inherit* or *derive* from it (not implement, as your question said, but you might mean this).

```
Public MustInherit Class Foo
    Sub Bar()
        Console.WriteLine("Bar")
    End Sub
    MustOverride Sub Barr()
End Class
```

If you give this to people in a code file, they can change what happens in `Bar()` or really do anything they want to it. Again, putting this in a .NET assembly and giving the .dll to people would prevent this from happening. In most cases this is enough to keep people from changing your code.

You can do this by making the output type of your project a class library. This will compile into a .dll file.

[image]

Build the project. In the output directory will be a .dll file (if compilation was a success).

You, or other people, could then add a reference to the .dll file created by your class library, in a new project. You could declare a class which implements the public interface defined in it

```
Public Class MyIFoo
    Implements WindowsApplication1.IFoo

    Public Sub Bar() Implements WindowsApplication1.IFoo.Bar

    End Sub
End Class
```

And/or make a class which inherits the abstract class you made in the .dll

```
Public Class MyFoo
    Inherits WindowsApplication1.Foo

    Public Overrides Sub Barr()

    End Sub
End Class
```

In your new project, *you cannot see or change the code of the Interface IFoo or abstract class Foo*.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `private` keyword to prevent a client of the class from accessing or modifying fields directly. You expose the methods and properties you want the client to access via the `public` or `protected` keyword (for inheritance).

Comment: How does this answer have anything to do with "allow people to implement a class" or "without letting them see or change the code"?

Comment: @Verdolino My earlier interpretation of the somewhat ambiguous question lead me to this answer. Alfie may well have been referring to creating an assembly instead, in which case your answer is great!